# Rotation throws object out of collision box blender game engine

Tags: mesh, game-engine

Whenever I create a rotating condition in my game, my mesh gets thrown out of the collision box and sort of orbits the box which causes it to look very odd and not function. Any Ideas how I can fix this? 
[image: (Croc not rotated at all, stays in collision box)]

[image: (Croc rotated a small amount, flies out of collision box)]

PIC 1 (Croc not rotated at all, stays in collision box)
PIC 2 (Croc rotated a small amount, flies out)

Comment: What type of physics have the crorc and the box? can u show the configuration, your question doesn't show as much information needed.

Answer (score 0):

Mostlikely you have an inhomogene scaling at one of the parent objects.

I suggest to apply <kbd>ctrl+a</kbd> `Scale` to ensure it is (1,1,1) at all parents.